# Odd behaviour on track bar mouse move event

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am trying to implement a feature similar to most media players where by moving your mouse above the media duration track bar it will display a small popup informing you on the time your mouse is currently above. I noticed an odd behaviour though while implementing the code given below.

```
procedure TForm1.TrackBar1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Single);
var
  pers: Extended;
begin
  pers := (X/TrackBar1.Width);
  PixelLabel.Text := FloatToStr(pers * TrackBar1.Max);
end;
```

If I click in the middle of the track bar I will get a value quite close to the actual track bar value at that point, so if for example the track bar range goes from **0** to **2000** and I click somewhere in the middle I get **1000**, but as I move to the left or right I start to get smaller and bigger values respectively. So if my mouse is close to the start for example I might get **180** instead of **100** that should be the actual value at that point. Can someone point out what is it that I am doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

By actual track bar value what I mean is the value derived from:

```
procedure TForm1.TrackBar1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ActualLabel.Text := 'Actual Val: '+FloatToStr(TrackBar1.Value);

end;
```

So I will move the mouse lets say at position 308 (the track bar goes from 0 to 609 here) and I will get a *perch* value of 0.50574 that is telling me that the value of the track bar under the mouse at position 308 is 10114, but by clicking the mouse and firing up the onChange function I get a value of 10116. This difference sends to increase as we go further from the middle of the track bar to either one of its sides.

**EDIT 2**

A clearer example would be this. As seen in the image below I move the mouse at position X=572. This position if expressed as a percentage for the whole track bar would be 572/609 = 0,9392. So one would expect that the percentage of the value of the track bar at that position (min:0 - max:200 as the image shows) would be the same. In other words,  MValue/max = 0,9392.

[image]

But after clicking the track bar at that exact position and then requesting its value it won't return what I computed as 'MValue' as the image below shows (Mouse is not visible but this image is indeed after I clicked the track bar in the same position, as you can see the ActualValue was updated)

[image]

Comment: Try `TrackBar1.ClientWidth` instead of `Width` although I don't think that would be too big of a difference. The idea is that the actual track is a few pixels smaller than the control's width.

Comment: ClientWidth is not a property of track bar, if you mean absolute width i did try it but its the exact same thing.

Comment: I just noticed you're using Firemonkey, but the concept is the same, the actual track bar itself is smaller than the control's width. You have to identify the width of the actual track, and there are probably no straight-forward properties to tell you this information.

Comment: The same problem exists in VCL. It's just having to get to a lower level to get this track's width, which is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Have you ever thought about using some other component instead. For istance you could use TGauge instead so you get result similar as in BS Player or Cyberlink Power DVD. Main advantage of TGauge is that since it doesen't have any extra space on left and right side you can easily use Width for calculating the position as you did in your original code.

Comment: @Silver TGauge?!! That ancient 16 bit vcl control? This is an fmx question.

Comment: Pardon me. I forgot that there is no TGauge for firemonkey by default but I managed to find a code that adds TGauge like component for firemonkey http://www.delphipraxis.net/1255996-post9.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem 1**

Your calculation of value does not match that used by the control. The control does it with this code which can be found in `FMX.StdCtrls`:

```
function PosToValue(MinValue, MaxValue, ViewportSize, ThumbSize, TrackSize, 
  Pos: Single; IgnoreViewportSize: boolean): Single;
var ValRel: Double;
begin
  Result := MinValue;
  if (ViewportSize < 0) or IgnoreViewportSize then
    ViewportSize := 0;
  ValRel := TrackSize - ThumbSize;
  if ValRel > 0 then
  begin
    ValRel := (Pos - ThumbSize / 2) / ValRel;
    if ValRel < 0 then
      ValRel := 0;
    if ValRel > 1 then
      ValRel := 1;
    Result := MinValue + ValRel * (MaxValue - MinValue - ViewportSize);
  end;
end;
```

The difference is that the code here makes an allowance for the thumb size. You formula is equivalent to calling this function and passing a value of `0` for `ThumbSize`.

If you want to replicate the behaviour of the control, then you'll need to use this algorithm also. You'll need the protected hack to crack the class.

```
type
  THackedTrackBar = class(TTrackBar);

procedure TForm1.TrackBar1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; 
  X, Y: Single);
var
  tb: THackedTrackBar;
begin
  tb := THackedTrackBar(TrackBar1);
  Label1.Text := FloatToStr(
    PosToValue(
      tb.Min,
      tb.Max,
      tb.ViewportSize,
      tb.GetThumbSize(tb.FIgnoreViewportSize),
      tb.Width,
      X,
      tb.FIgnoreViewportSize
    )
  );
end;
```

**Problem 2**

`OnMouseMove` does not fire when the cursor is over the track thumb. This seems to be a basic limitation of the FMX `TTrackBar` control. The underlying framework is obviously aware that the cursor is over the thumb because it paints it in a different colour, the so-called hot-tracking effect. However, the framework appears to do this to the detriment of letting you know that the mouse is moving.

The thumb on the track bar is implemented as a separate object. It's an object of type `TThumb`. The `TTrackBar` control exposes the object via a protected property. You can use the protected hack to get hold of the thumb object and then set its `OnMouseMove` event handler. Not a whole lot of fun, but certainly one way to work around the issue.

Comment: Yes indeed, but track thumb aside, what my real issue is, is the fact that those values aren't as expected. Let me update the question with the code showing how I get the what I've called "actual" track bar value.

Comment: The values are just fine here. For my track bar with min of 0 and max of 100, your code produces values ranging from 0 to 100. But not when tracking the thumb. I'm using XE7 as I presume you are.

Comment: Yes, indeed it produces values from min to max as it should ut those values for some reason differ from what the track bar itself actually thinks as the correct value under that position. Check my edit of a better understanding of the issue.

Comment: I think that you understand your problem. But it's hard for us. How about a bit more in the question. Perhaps some screenshots. Anyway, I now understand the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update to the question. This is now excellent. I think I managed to work it all out anyway as you can see in my update.

Comment: One last thing. In order to do the hack you mentioned and access classes of the TTrackbar object do I need to use something like THackedTrackBar(TrackBar1) ?

Comment: Well yeah it was not needed in the end as you managed to solve the issue before i complete it :P

Comment: Yeah, the code in my answer for Problem 1 shows how to get at protected members. That's a pretty standard trick. Yes, I worked out the Q before your update, but now the Q is much more useful to future visitors. So thanks again for your time and effort in making it a useful resource.

Answer (score 0):

For your initial problem you will need to dig into the style to find the exact amount of left and right padding around the track bar. Note though that this will vary depending on the platform, style and Delphi version.

You might consider using your own style so you know everything will be constant.

To solve the issue raised by David Heffernan you could put a transparent control over the TTrackBar (make it a client aligned child of the track bar), intercept mouse events, do your own processing and pass them down to the track bar.

Comment: That shouldn't be the issue, because if you check the value of X as you move the mouse it correctly reports 0 at the start and 609 at the end of a track bar with position.x = 0 width = 609.

Comment: And you're saying Position.X = 0 when the mouse is over the extreme left (lowest position) of the trackbar? If so then you seem to be directly contradicting your own question.

Comment: How so? Also maybe checking the accepted answer might give you a better idea of what I meant.